# Getting nearest text box to radio button in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble getting the text box nearest to my selected radio button. Here is what I have tried so far which keeps returning me 'undefined'.

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="capacity-field">
    <legend>Capacity</legend>
    <table style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="capacity" value="raw" checked>Raw (TB):
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="raw-capacity" value="256" size="2"> TB
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="capacity" value="usable">Usable (TB):
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="usable-capacity" value="161.28" size="2"> TB
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="capacity" value="effective">Effective (TB):
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="effective-capacity" value="161.28" size="2"> TB
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
function cap_growth_update(toUpdate) {
    var capacity = $("input[name='capacity']:checked").next("input[type='text']").val();
    alert(capacity);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     cap_growth_update("T");
});
```

I know the value of `toUpdate` is arbitrary at this point, but it will be used as a selector later down the line and thus is included.

Comment: You should use `.next` when you want to find an element inside the base element's parent, which is next to it. In your case, a `capacity`'s parent is a `td`, but it doesn't have any other elements, ther's nothing to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery next() function looks for a sibling element, but since these elements are separated under different td elements, you'll have to climb up the DOM:

```
$("input[name='capacity']:checked").closest("tr").find("input[type='text']").val();
```

So what it does, is to go to the closest  parent, and then search for the children text input.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) with [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and  [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("input[name='capacity']:checked").parents().eq(1).find("input[type='text']").val();
```

Note this is only a suggestion I make based on your markup, your goal could be achieved in other ways (jQuery is a rich library to traverse and manipulate DOM)

Comment: Could you please explain this? I really don't want to leave with an answer without understanding its underlying logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("input:radio").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var value = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:text").val();
        }
    });    
});
```

The code checks for a click event on a radio element then check if the element is checked, if it's checked then obtain the parent row of the radio element, find an input text inside the row an get the value of the input text the it saves the value at the var value, so you can do whatever with the value :)

Regards!

Comment: Please consider adding at least a little sentence to explain why and how your code snippet does answer the OP question.

Comment: Ok, i'm new at this :), the code checks for a click event on a radio element then check if the element is checked, if it's checked then obtain the parent row of the radio element, find an input text inside the row an get the value of the input text the it saves the value at the var value, so you can do whatever with the value :) Regards!

Comment: Better. Now, instead of a comment, edit your answer and put this explanation in the answer itself, and you'll have a well written answer.